# IF, CASE, WHEN Statements Returning different rows of a table depending on a certain value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I want to write a SQL query which returns a part of a table (not a returns new table).

An `If, Case` or whatever statement should decide which rows are returned.

The statement should look at a specific value in a column 'comments' (type `VARCHAR`) of a specific ID which can be 'new' or 'played'.

If the 'comments' is LIKE '%new%' then the query should select ID 1, 2 and 3, else if the 'comments' is LIKE '%played%' then the query should select ID 4.

I cannot get this running cause I only find examples which are changing values in a table but not selecting rows.

I hope someone can help me :)

---

**A new approach to explain the problem**

If the value of the column `comments` in the row with the ID = 2 is `'new'` then the query should select the rows with the IDs 1, 2 and 3.

Input table:

```
ID   title   comments
---------------------
1    title1  sth
2    title2  *new*
3    title3    
4    title4  sth
```

Expected output:

```
ID   title   comments
---------------------
1    title1  sth
2    title2  new
3    title3
```

Else if the value of the column `comments` in the row with the ID = 2 is 'played' then the query should select the row with the ID 4.

Input table (Note that the value in 'comments' in ID 2 has changed)

```
ID   title   comments
---------------------
1    title1  sth
2    title2  *played*
3    title3    
4    title4  sth
```

Expected output:

```
ID   title   comments
---------------------
4    title4  sth
```

This is the code I thought would do the task but it isn't

```
IF (SELECT comments FROM table WHERE ID = 2) LIKE 'new'
    SELECT ID, title, comments 
    FROM table 
    WHERE ID = 1 OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3

IF (SELECT comments FROM table WHERE ID = 2) LIKE 'played'
    SELECT ID, title, comments 
    FROM table 
    WHERE ID = 4
```

Comment: Not really following, what are you trying to do?
Show me the expected output here

Comment: So... 1,2,3 is always related to new, and 4 is always related to played. Or what is the deal? The logic behind this eludes me.

Comment: Maybe explain the end goal (instead of the sql you're trying to use).. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Crucial: CASE *expression*. (and: there is no IF in SQL)

Comment: You syntax for IF expression seems to be incorrect. `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

Comment: Syntax for IF expression is incorrect. Here's the correct syntax for IF `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.title, t1.comments 
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table1 t2
    ON ((t1.ID = 1 OR t1.ID = 2 OR t1.ID = 3) AND t2.comments LIKE 'new') OR
       (t1.ID = 4 AND t2.comments LIKE 'played')
WHERE t2.ID = 2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=593d8e703006322f9a77df60e9985b1f

Answer (score 0):

Id you don't want to use proceddure with its flow control.

you can always switch to dynamic sql

```
SELECT IF ((SELECT comments FROM table_a WHERE ID = 2) LIKE 'new',
@sql := 'SELECT ID, title, comments FROM table_a WHERE ID = 1 OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3',
IF ((SELECT comments FROM table_a WHERE ID = 2) LIKE 'played', @sql :=
'SELECT ID, title, comments FROM table_a WHERE ID = 4', @sql := 'SELECT SLEEP(0)'));

  PREPARE Stnt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE Stnt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE Stnt;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer. That works. Is there any way to return only one table (the second) or "hide" the first table when the correct query is selected?

Comment: no, hiding is impossible with this approach, bud you can  hide it in a procedure so you would only see `call myprocedure`